# Div wont stop scrolling with Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using my code at:
http://jsfiddle.net/Pd7nm/

I want the sidebar to stop scrolling with the page at a certain point but it just keeps on going. I have tried multiple things and its not working.

This is the Javascript Method thingy

```
 var windw = this;
$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
var $this = this,
    $window = $(windw);

$window.scroll(function(e){
    if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: pos
        });
    } else {
        $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0
        });
    }
});
};

$('#side').followTo(250);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated JQuery Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pd7nm/23/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(height>250){
        $(".sidebar").css({"position":"fixed","top":0});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but I believe you have what i'm trying to do seen wrong. Im trying to make it so when the user scrolls past the content and div sidebar it will no longer scroll along the page, its a bit confusing I understand :)

Comment: Actually when scrollTop() becomes 250, it is getting fixed but not getting top 0

Comment: It still seems to scroll with the screen for me :? Running Chrome if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

See This demos I have removed in "br" tag

```
Demos - jsfiddle.net/Nu3eu/1/
```

Comment: That doesn't stop the div continuing to go with the screen. Running Chrome if that helps.

Comment: Looking like in Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 m

Comment: Ok so, these are the results i'm getting this is the page normally https://cloudup.com/cEfgJD4xpSs and I want it to stop scrolling the Sidebar element when the page gets to https://cloudup.com/ctyhibnclOU there. Is that what your code is supposed to do? if so its not working on my end >_>